# Как вставить значение переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть строка,работает

```
console.log(data.array[0].sofa_3[0].rusname);
```

Как можно, вставить вместо `rusname` ,переменную?
Например

```
var id="engname";
console.log(data.array[0].sofa_3[0].+id);
```

Знаю,что ошибочно, но как то так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать скобочную нотацию:

```
console.log(data.array[0].sofa_3[0][id]);
```